# Не добавляется фотография через форму

Tags: django

Не добавляется фотография через форму(фотография типа **FileField**). Через админку при создании записи - всё добавляется, а через форму на сайте нет. Я выбираю файл, жму создать и сама запись сохраняется в БД, все поля нормально отображаются, а фотография нет. Вот сама форма:

```
class AdsForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Ads
            fields = ['title','text','price','image','category']
    
            widgets = {
                'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Заголовок'}),
                'text':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Описание'}),
                'price':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Цена'}),
                'image':forms.FileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
                'category':forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            }
```

***View класс наследуется от FormView.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего в html файле в форме не указано
`enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Comment: Да проблема была именно в этом. Теперь буду знать, спасибо вам за помощь!